# Bookshelf.js create a model on a hasMany through relation

Tags: mysql, bookshelf.js

Here is what my relation looks like:

```
    days: function() {
        return this.hasMany('Day').through('Schedule');
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
                var payload = _.extend(request.payload, {
                    create_user: request.auth.credentials.id,
                    update_user: request.auth.credentials.id
                });
                var currentProject = request.app.currentProject();

                return currentProject.then(function(project) {
                    return project.days().create(payload);
                }).then(function(model) {
                    return reply(model).code(201);
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    return reply(Boom.wrap(err));
                });
```

I'm getting a MySQL error of stack: `Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (my_db.day, CONSTRAINT fk_day_schedule FOREIGN KEY (schedule_id) REFERENCES schedule (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

Comment: Did you get a solution?